# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки определялось текущее местоположение и ставилась метка на это место?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api, map, onclicklistener

Вот фрагмент кода, не могу понять, что мне вписать в метод OnClick

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mylocation = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mylocation);

    View.OnClickListener mylocation = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             mylocation.???;

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private View.OnTouchListener handleTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        (ImageButton)myLocation.setX((здесь cast по-моему)x);
        (ImageButton)myLocation.setY(y);
    }


    return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: кнопка в приложении никак не срабатывает.

Comment: @A.Whole с назначеным слушателем? окей, я позже посмотрю у себя в студии

Comment: Код сам чистый, но ничего не делает.

Comment: @A.Whole momento